# How to print arabic character on a full graphic LCD

Tags: c, lcd

I am stuck on finding a way how to write into my full graphic LCD with Arabic characters or how to include the ASCII Arabic code. Should I simply declare a `(const char *)` and write into it whatever I want or how to proceed? I tried this way to draw whatever character I want but it didn't work.

```
byte customChar[8] = { 0b00000, 0b01010, 0b11111, 0b11111,  
                       0b01110, 0b00100, 0b00000, 0b00000 };
```

I am using full graphic LCD 128 x 64 dots (Sitronix ST7567A) connected to my uC using I2C interface.

Comment: Please [edit] to include link to datasheet. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see you followed my advice to post your question here. However, I also explained at [your post on ST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790461/how-to-print-arabic-character-on-a-full-graphic-lcd) the other problems that you should fix before posting it. However, you copy-pasted the exact question without any modifications :-(

Comment: "but it didn't work" is not much of a problem description. What were you expecting to happen, what exactly *did* happen?

Answer (score 2):

It's not so easy… these panels are just a bunch of pixel so you need some kind of graphic library to drive them *and* the bitmaps for all the characters you want to use. It's not excessively difficult but you could run in memory issue if you don't have a lot of NVM storage.

The problem is not inherent to arabic, that controller has no support for text whatsoever (there are around controller with a font rom but usually for latin and/or chinese, never seen them for arabic). Even for showing a simple 'A' you need to send the pixel pattern to the display memory

Comment: Notably, one can also find character ROM chips, with a simple SPI memory interface, like [this one (ER3300-1)](https://www.buydisplay.com/font-chip-font-ic-er3300-1-supports-gb12345-big5-ascii-unicode-sop8), which also seems to support Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Greek, Cyrillic, Latin with diacritics, and several sizes of ASCII. (I have no affiliation with buydisplay.com, and I have no idea how would one actually render Arabic text; let that be an exercise for the reader :') )  Of course, one could also use an off-the-shelf SPI flash and use it to store their own custom character sets/bitmaps.

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcantonio I didn't understand how to write an arabic string on my IDE at first for example to declare an english string we can proceed as follow `const char stLCD[4] = {'L', 'C', 'D', '\0'};`. but for declaring مرحبا for example i don't know how.

Comment: @kakachi_hatake then it's an *encoding* problem then. Unless you have a newer compiler which understand unicode literals (don't know if you can in C, the lastest C++ can) you need to use the raw hex values or rely on compiler-specific behaviour. Try asking in the programming community

Comment: It isn't rocket science to build up a font from raw bitmaps, given that you can get the actual font from somewhere (the Internet). The real problem will be to get your source code to correspond with the symbol table. C supports wide characters but you need to translate those to your symbol table indices. Hint: do this for English first, get it up and running, then consider other languages as project 2.